# How to use SklearnClassifier on Counter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk

I have some lists represented by their bigrams, and how many times they each occur. The bigrams come from a vocabulary made from alle unique bigrams. I would like to use the SklearnClassifier(SVC) on this

The code I've made so far:

```
 train_ngrams = [(train_filtered_tweets[i], train_filtered_tweets[i + 1]) for
 i in range(len(train_filtered_tweets) - 1)]
 print "Tweets from train set as bigrams", Counter(train_ngrams)

 classif = SklearnClassifier(BernoulliNB()).train(train_ngrams)
 classify = SklearnClassifier(SVC(), sparse=False).train(Counter(train_ngrams))
 print classify
```

But I get the error :

```
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

I think that it is because my train_ngrams is not the feature vector, but I'm not sure how to make it.

Answer (score 1):

Your training data also needs the specific target label. Consider this example pulled from the nltk [website](http://www.nltk.org/howto/classify.html):

```
>>> from nltk.classify import SklearnClassifier
>>> from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
>>> from sklearn.svm import SVC
>>> train_data = [({"a": 4, "b": 1, "c": 0}, "ham"),
...               ({"a": 5, "b": 2, "c": 1}, "ham"),
...               ({"a": 0, "b": 3, "c": 4}, "spam"),
...               ({"a": 5, "b": 1, "c": 1}, "ham"),
...               ({"a": 1, "b": 4, "c": 3}, "spam")]
>>> classif = SklearnClassifier(BernoulliNB()).train(train_data)
>>> test_data = [{"a": 3, "b": 2, "c": 1},
...              {"a": 0, "b": 3, "c": 7}]
>>> classif.classify_many(test_data)
['ham', 'spam']
>>> classif = SklearnClassifier(SVC(), sparse=False).train(train_data)
>>> classif.classify_many(test_data)
['ham', 'spam']
```

As you can see, the target labels are **ham** or **spam**. Also, you seem to be using a `Counter` object, while the API is looking for a list of tuples, which has the dictionary of word counts in each tuple, along with the label. I don't know what target label you have created for your corpus of tweets, but I can tell you how to generate the dictionary of bi-gram frequencies for your corpus, assuming your corpus is an iterable where each element is a tweet.

```
mybigramlist = []
for tweet in corpus:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(tweet)
    bgs = nltk.bigrams(tokens)  # get the bigrams
    freqs = nltk.FreqDist(bgs)  # this is dictionary of the bigrams with their frequencies in the tweet
    mybigramlist.append(freqs)
```

Now all you have to do is figure out what your labels are and then make the final training data that adheres the structure in the given documentation.

Comment: I tried to use this, but all I get is a none in return? Do you know why that is.

Comment: Is your corpus a list of tweets. E.g. `corpus = ["real unicorns among us narwhals", "this is tweet two", "tweet three is positive sentiment!"]`? Also, if you're looking at tweets, it might be better to use [TweetTokenizer](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.casual.TweetTokenizer)

Comment: The data set is just a lot of tweets, i'm trying to use the classifier on data that looks like this; [('1', 'hello'), ('hello', 'says'), ('says', 'someone'), ('someone', 'country'), ('country', 'fasting')]
[('2', 'happy'), ('happy', 'sad'), ('sad', 'python'), ('pythoin', 'never'), ('never', 'commit')]

Comment: Hmmm, so it does look like the bigrams are already generated in your data. It just needs to have the counts for the bigrams in a dictionary format.